# css header issue in html5

Tags: css, html

```
<header id="header">
  <img src="http://s30.postimg.org/rlkl06s9d/logo.jpg" alt="logo" id="logo">
  <h1>The Articles</h1>
  <nav class="header-nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> Articles </a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

css:

```
#header{
    margin:10px;
}

#logo
{
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    border-bottom: solid 2px #CCC;
}
```

Here the header "The Articles" and navigation need to place on same line and navigation need to place on the right side of page.

I need like this:

```
The articles                                                     Home      Articles
```

May i know what is the exact css property to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option.

[**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/h820o6pp/)

```
#header h1 {
    float: left;
}
#header nav {
    float: right;
}

#header nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your css like below.

```
#header h1{float:left;}
#header nav.header-nav{float:right;}
#header nav.header-nav li{display:inline-block;}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/d66arbar/1/)